# reading files in R

Tags: r

I've been searching for a solution for my problem in many topics but i couldn't find the answere. I have a dozen of files i'm trying to read from directory but nothing seems to work.
I tried this in a first place:

```
files <- list.files(path="../..")
files1 <- lapply(files, read.table, header=TRUE, sep="", skip=5)
```

and this:

```
files <- list.files(path="../..")
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
files1 <- read.table(files[i], header=TRUE, sep="",skip=5)
}
```

it says error file(file, "rt") can't open such file or directory, though when i do >files, it lists all the files.

where's the mistake? tx

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem. Windows?

Comment: try `list.files(path="../..", full.names = TRUE)`.

Comment: is it just me, or are you listing files from one path and trying to access them from another?

Comment: The point is, i wanna take only the first row with specific columns from each file and put them in a list all together. I could read the files when i did full.names. though  finally i get to read them with **full.names**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.files` gives you the file names, where as you need the whole path name.

One option is to paste the full path to the files list: `paste("path/to/files/", files, sep="/")`

The other option, as @BenBarnes points out, is to use the `full.names` argument in `list.files()`

Comment: yes i worked with **full.names**, now i wanna take only the first row with 3 columns from each file into a list. can i handle it this way?

Comment: @user2207085 subset the resulting object by the coulmns, e.g. `(read.table(files[i], header=TRUE, sep="", skip=5 , nrow = 1 ))[,1:3]` and stop appending new questions and conditions after the question has been answered. Either outline your problem properly to begin with, or if the situation warrants, ask a new question.

Comment: @user2207085, to echo what Simon Says _(see what I just did there, that was a funny pun)_  it is perfectly acceptable to ask a new question related to a previous one. If the background is needed, just link back to the original question.  Asking a new question in the comments can get irritating, as Simon so elegantly points out. :)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta tyvm. It took me a lot of time to finally get the work done. I understand, It wouldn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the `plyr` package for this type of thing. Depending on how you plan on using the files, you may need to use a different l*ply function:

```
require(plyr)
files <- dir("../..", full= TRUE)
data <- llply(files, read.table, header= T, sep= "", skip= 5)
```

This would give you a list of 12 (or however many) datasets.